# Can't install Upwork application on Ubuntu 15 with gksu

Tags: apt, dependencies, gksu

I am not able to install Upwork 64 bit application on Ubuntu, reason I am asking this again as I followed the answer posted in another similar question but I could not get it working.

I am having issues while installing gksu

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
upwork: Depends: gksu but it is not installed
        Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:5.2.1-22ubuntu2 is installed
        Depends: libnspr4 (>= 4.10.7-0) but 2:4.10.8-2ubuntu1 is installed
        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 5.2.1-22ubuntu2 is installed
        Depends: libudev1 (>= 198) but 225-1ubuntu9 is installed
        Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2 is installed
        Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but 1:0.4.4-1 is installed
        Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.4-2 is installed
        Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.4-1 is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try two way to solve this issue:

1. Try to fix package dependencies automatically
2. Manually install packages needed by `Upwork`

**First Solution:**
Run the following command that should fix packages dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

More information about this command can be read in the manual with this command:

```
man apt-get
```

Second Solution:
Watch at all packages that aren't installed and install them. In this case seems that you only need `gksu` package, while the other packages have all a greater version than the required and this is not a problem. To install `gksu` run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Now you can try to install `Upwork` and shouldn't get any package dependencies error.

I hope this could help you.